# What mount option to use for ext3 file system to minimise data loss or corruption?

Tags: mount, ext3, journaling

I have an embedded setup using an initramfs for the root file system but using a custom ext3 partition mounted on a compact flash IDE drive. Because data integrity in the face of power loss is the most important factor in the entire setup, I have used the following options to mount (below is the entry from my `/etc/fstab` file

```
<file system> <mount pt> <type> <options>                         <dump><pass>
/dev/sda2     /data      ext3   auto,exec,relatime,sync,barrier=1 0     2
```

I came by these options from reading around on the internet. What I am worried about is that the content of `/proc/mounts` give the following:

```
/dev/sda2 /data ext3 rw,sync,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,
barrier=1,data=writeback 0 0
```

From what I understand from reading around is that I want to use `data=journal` option for my mount as this offers the best protection against data corruption. However, from the man page for specific ext3 options for `mount` it says the 
following about the writeback option:

> Data ordering is not preserved - data may be written into the main
>   filesystem after its metadata has been committed to the journal.
>   This is rumoured to be the highest-throughput option. **It guarantees
>   internal filesystem integrity**, however it can allow old data to appear
>   in files after a crash and journal recovery.

I am very confused about this - the man page seems to suggest that for file system integrity I want to specify `data=writeback` option to `mount` but most other references I have found (including some published books on embedded linux) suggest that I should be using `data=journal`. What would be the best approach for me to use? Write speed is not an issue at all - data integrity is though.

Comment: [Provides some guidance around data=journal](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-ext3.html). I'd be inclined to use that over anything else since RH only supports that type of ordering.

Comment: @sim actually it says `data=ordered` :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't get misled by the fact that only `writeback` mentions `internal filesystem integrity`.
With `ext3`, whether you use `journal`, `ordered` or `writeback`, file system metadata is always [journalled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Journaling_levels) and that means internal file system integrity.

The *[data modes](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/ext3.txt#160)* offer a way of control over how *ordinary* data is written to the file system.
In `writeback` mode, *metadata changes are first recorded in the journal and a commit block is written. After the journal has been updated, metadata and data write-outs may proceed.* `data=writeback` *can be a severe security risk: if the system crashes while appending to a file, after the metadata has been committed (and additional data blocks allocated), but before the data has been written (data blocks overwritten with new data), then after journal recovery that file may contain blocks filled with data from previously deleted files – from any user*<sup>[1](http://monolight.cc/2011/06/barriers-caches-filesystems/)</sup>.

So, if data integrity is your main concern and speed is not important, `data=journal` is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

As you have already noticed, main point is that you cannot prevent your filesystem from all kind of crash.

What you can do:

1. On software side, you can use *fdatawrites* after each important operation (See [this 2003 post](http://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2003-October/msg00027.html) from Theodore T'so, a main Linux FS Kernel developer. it's still true. There's also [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/317781/comments/45) about a major data loss hidden in older versions of ext4)
2. Reduce commit interval to 1 second (*commit=1*)  (see [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/322823/) from LWN, it's about ext4 but contains really usefull informations about ext3). NB: It shouldn't be needed, with *sync*.
3. As RHEL doc pointed by sim said, use *data_err=abort* and *data=ordered*
4. *noatime* will reduce useless operations on filesystem
5. As you have already noticed, *barrier=1* is a good way to minimize data loss (see [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ext3.user/4206))
6. And *sync* is also, of course, one of the "I don't want to lose my data" option.

At the end, paranoiac mount options can look like this:

```
auto,exec,relatime,sync,barrier=1,commit=1,data=ordered,data_err=abort,noatime,
```

And you can also ensure data integrity with an automatic fsck at each boot.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing which part of the man page you empahsize:

> **writeback**
>
> > **Data  ordering is not preserved** - data may be written into the main filesystem after its metadata has been committed to the journal.  This is rumoured to be the highest-throughput option.  It guarantees internal filesystem integrity, **however it can allow old data to appear in files after a crash and journal recovery.**

As don_crissti pointed out, the other modes don't have the "however".