# Is there any way to perform fsck automatically after power failure?

Tags: fsck, external-hdd, ext3, headless

I have a *USB HDD* with an *ext3* file system, (it's a Plex server media drive), connected to my *Raspberry Pi*, and after power failure it is not mounting automatically and has a superblock reading problem. After performing `fsck` on the drive it comes back to fully working condition.

The problem is - my *Raspberry* is headless server and there is a power failure almost everyday where I live now, so I need to `ssh` every time and do `fsck` to get the disk running again. Is there any way to:

1. Perform `fsck` automatically (including answering the "*yes*" question)?
2. Detect a power failure so it will do it on boot?

Comment: Please specify the *file system* of the USB drive.  Tell us how the USB drive is being used when the power supply is steady -- *i.e.* are there a lot of disk writes, or does the R. PI server mainly run in RAM with a bit of network IO but few disk writes?

Comment: The file system is ext3, it holds media for Plex server and sometimes downloading video from youtube so not writing all the time.

Answer (score 1):

To force fsck on each boot, set the count-down to 1 in the root filesystem:

```
tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

If `tune2fs` is not installed, it can be found in the `e2fsprogs` package.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do so is to add a command

```
touch /forcefsck
```

in your `/etc/rc.local`.

This creates a file `forcefsck` in the root dir each time the machine starts, which tells fsck to run upon next reboot.

Note that fsck will remove that file after checking the filesystem -- that's why you need to recreate it each time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the system being an *ext3* file system used for Plex server media storage, the best thing might be to switch from the *ext3* file system's default journal mode of [`data=ordered` to its safest mode `data=journal`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129507/165517).  The write speed hit shouldn't be a big deal on a media server, and a data journal should eliminate the need for any `fsck`.

Depending on the hardware, other tweaks might be necessary to make it work better, such as disabling the USB drive's cache, (*if* that turns out to be a problem), or putting the data journal on a separate device, (such as a small SSD).